# how to use alias in the like condition

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```php
<?php
public function coassign_by_me($leadbm,$clbm,$cnbm)
{
    $rep_id=$this->session->userdata('TechUser_Id');
    $rows=$this->db->select("pm1coassign_lead.ticket_id, pm1category.category_name, pm1ticket.subject, pm1ticket.updt_date, pm1contact.id, concat(pm1contact.f_name, ' ', pm1contact.l_name) as client, pm1contact.phonefax, pm1ticket.rep_id as t_rep, rep1.user_name as rep1, rep2.user_name as rep2, pm1status.rep_display, pm1ticket.due_date",false);
    $this->db->from('pm1coassign_lead',true);
    $this->db->join('pm1ticket','pm1ticket.id=pm1coassign_lead.ticket_id');
    $this->db->join('pm1category','pm1category.id=pm1ticket.category_id');
    $this->db->join('pm1contact','pm1contact.id=pm1ticket.customer_id');
    $this->db->join('pm1contact_rep as rep1','pm1ticket.rep_id=rep1.id');
    $this->db->join('pm1contact_rep as rep2','pm1coassign_lead.coassign_rep=rep2.id');
    $this->db->join('pm1status','pm1ticket.status_id=pm1status.id'); 
    $this->db->where('coassign_by',$rep_id);
    if(!empty($leadbm) && $leadbm != ''){
        $this->db->where_in("pm1coassign_lead.ticket_id",$leadbm);
    }
    if(!empty($clbm) && $clbm !=''){
        $this->db->like('client',$clbm);
    }
    if(!empty($cnbm) && $cnbm != ''){
        $this->db->where_in("pm1contact.phonefax",$cnbm);
    }
    $array = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
    return $array->result_array();
}
?>
```

here i have a query where how can i use client in like condition. i am getting confusion. can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` clause for custom declared identifiers. like below

```
if(!empty($clbm) && $clbm !='') {
    $this->db->having("client like '%$clbm%'");
}
```

**Note :** Whenever you are declaring a custom identifier, You have to use `HAVING` clause to apply `WHERE` condition on it. and having clause must be after `GROUP BY` clause and before `ORDER BY` clause.

In your case it will be in this order

```
if(!empty($leadbm) && $leadbm != ''){
    $this->db->where_in("pm1coassign_lead.ticket_id",$leadbm);
}
if(!empty($cnbm) && $cnbm != ''){
    $this->db->where_in("pm1contact.phonefax",$cnbm);
}
if(!empty($clbm) && $clbm !='') {
    $this->db->having("client like '%$clbm%'");
}
```

Hope it helps.